# android Swipe completely hidden view up and down with bottomsheet or viewdraghelper

Tags: android, bottom-sheet, viewdraghelper

In my android app I need to create a view that user can slide up and down with finger. Not just `slide` up/down with `swipe/fling` but slide up/down when finger is held down on screen.

Like [Snapchat Memories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NgcwT.jpg) slide view.

I have tried using `BottomSheetDialog` but problem is, I need to keep a `peekHeight` in order to swipe as I require it. If I use `BottomSheetDialogFragment` and set `peekHeight` to `0` then I need to use `show()` on `FragmentManager` which just leaves me with two options; to set `peekHeight` or expand completely.

There is a utility class called `ViewDragHelper`. I saw some examples but again, all examples showed the view partially visible in order to drag it up/down.

Is there any way, I could use `BottomSheetDialog` or `BottomSheetDialogFragment` and create user swipe like **snapchat memories**.
If `ViewDragHelper` can be used could someone provide me with an example where **view is completely hidden** at beginning? The reference docs are quite confusing.